# Adding parameters to a JQuery function

Tags: jquery

Beginners question about adding variables to a function:

Putting in the amounts :

```
var calcdiscount = function () {

    var test = $('#discount').val();
    if (test.length > 0 && $('#discount')[0].checkValidity()) {
        PizzaSizeCost(2);
    }
    else {
        PizzaSizeCost(0);
    }
}
;
```

Getting out the amount:

```
var PizzaSizeCost = function (test) {
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: `How can I do this ?` Do what?

Comment: How Can I put in the amount and get it out again? .... 
Obvious.../

Answer (score 2):

A `function` uses `return` to, well, return values to the caller. So:

```
function testValue(value) {
    if (value < 100) {
        return "Small";
    } else {
        return "Large";
    }
}

var example = testValue(75);
// Now example = "Small"
var secondExample = testValue(125);
// secondExample = "Large"
```

Comment: This is basic JavaScript by the way, not JQuery.